# convert "2017-10-11 11:45:30" to Oct 11,2017 in php

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

$date= "2017-10-11 11:45:30";

I have above date geting from database 
 I want convert into this date to Oct 11,2017

How to do this in PHP

Comment: Where is the content of `Dcd.php` ?

Answer (score 0):

you could use mktime and date to solve this problem:

```
<?php
    $datetime = "2017-10-11 11:45:30";

    list($date, $time) = explode(" ", $datetime);
    list($Y, $M, $D)   = explode("-", $date);
    list($h, $m, $s)   = explode(":", $time);

    $newdate = date("M d, Y", mktime(
        $h, $m, $s, $M, $D, $Y
    ));
    print($newdate);
?>
```

The Output would be "Oct 11, 2017".

Sincerely,
Sam.